# How to avoid i in roots of cubic

Tags: complex, equation-solving

For a general cubic Mathematica applies the formula and the output has i=sqrt(-1) in 2 of the roots.

```
Roots[A*x^3 + B*x^2 + C*x + D == 0, x]
```

I want the roots in a format that avoids i, keep the negative signs inside of square roots.

Comment: Sorry, but this is literally impossible.

Comment: Is it? the formula on Wikipedia is defined in a way that seems very possible, its just I have a more complicate equation, cant do that one by hand.

Comment: See here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casus_irreducibilis.

Comment: May be spell it as "roots of cubuc"? That gets rid of the "i"...

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: I am trying to get the 3rd order Bezier curve into cartesian form

Comment: Wanna take a look? https://www.desmos.com/calculator/csuhy2sdse see the blue curve is the cartesian form, for some curves it doesn't work. I worked this one out by taking one of the roots of x and plugging it in to y to eliminate t, the other roots are probably what I need to cover all the solutions

Comment: This appears to be an XY question: you should state in full the problem you actually wish to solve. From these comments I gather that you have parametric equations for `{x,y}` in terms of some other variable, call it `t`. They are (I presume) cubic polynomials. You then obtain an implicit equation in `{x,y}` and now want to solve for `y` in terms of `x`? That last step will run  into the  casus irreducibilis.